# What to do if I'm missing information from a booked visa appointment?

Tags: visas, uk

I am from Pakistan. I have taken an appointment for a UK visa in Lahore. After submitting online, I just noticed that I forgot to enter my GWF number in my wife's application in "Additional Notes". Just my passport number is mentioned.

Please let me know what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such compulsion. Don’t worry and go to your appointment. If you have answered all the questions correctly your applications will automatically get linked.

Your application will mention her passport number and hers will mention yours. A GWF is not the only thing to establish a link. If it was so important they would have listed it as a separate question. They don’t expect everyone to automatically know they have to put each other’s GWF numbers in notes.

When they take your documents they will link your applications and your documents will go to the decision center in 1 bag.